# MySQL: Get local time for a specific time zone

Tags: mysql, timezone

Here's a simple version of the table `users`:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
|      id      |     timezone      |
+--------------+-------------------+
|       1      | 'Europe/Helsinki' |
|       2      |  'Europe/Paris'   |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

I want to know what's the local time for each one of these users (depending on their time zones), so that I can select users for who it's 4pm for example.

I'm using the LAMP stack, but I'd like to do that using MySQL only (not selecting all users and running them in a PHP loop).

Comment: why don't you use CONVERT_TZ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Because I was a fool obviously. Knowing that my MySQL server is in France, `SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW( ) ,  'Europe/Paris',  'America/New_York' )` works perfectly fine! Please add an answer to this question stating this, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I often have that on a Friday afternoon :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the CONVERT_TZ for this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), server_tz, `timezone`))=16
```

Comment: i don't know what "server_tz" is. Just use @@session.time_zone to give you whatever the current timezone setting is on the connection.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the timezone with `set time_zone`:

```
mysql> set time_zone='Europe/Helsinki';
mysql> select now();
2012-09-21 16:15:06
mysql> set time_zone='Europe/Paris';
mysql> select now();
2012-09-21 15:15:40
```

Using this you can, for example, define a function that returns the current time for the user's timezone:

```
create function current_time_in_tz(tz varchar(40)) returns datetime 
begin
set @old_tz = @@session.time_zone;
set time_zone=tz;
set @now = now();
set time_zone=@old_tz;
return @now;
end

select id, current_time_in_tz(timezone) from users;
```

Note that DATE, TIME and DATETIME values don't depend on the time zone, so values from columns of these types are not automatically adjusted when querying. TIMESTAMP values are adjusted:

```
mysql> create temporary table tbl (dt datetime, ts timestamp);
mysql> insert into tbl values (now(),now());
mysql> select * from tbl;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| dt                  | ts                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-09-21 15:21:56 | 2012-09-21 15:21:56 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
mysql> set time_zone='Europe/Helsinki';
mysql> select * from tbl;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| dt                  | ts                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-09-21 15:21:56 | 2012-09-21 16:21:56 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

If `set time_zone` fails with this error:

```
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Helsinki'
```

you need to load the time zone info into mysql with a command like this:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

For more info see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: I already read that part of the manual, and it doesn't help. I need to handle several time zones in a single query, I can't do that by declaring a connection/server/system variable.

Comment: You can create a function that sets the variable, and call the function in the query... See update.

Comment: That would work, but @nin's answer is what I was looking for. Thank you though!

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about convert_tz and just assumed nothing like it exists!

Answer (score 5):

A more generic (not depending on the timezone of the server) solution than Nin's answer would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE hour( CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 'UTC', timezone) )=16
```

It would be nice if MySQL had a function like NOW_TZ(timezone).